# Virtual Column for Counting

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How I can get this virtual column in select statement in sqlserver

Sample EmpTable

```
EmpID     EmpName
1001      sample1
1002      test1
1003      sample2
1004      test2
1005      sample3
```

SQL Statement `Select virCol, EmpID, EmpName from EmpTable Where EmpName Like '%sam%'`

Sample Output

```
virCol   EmpID     EmpName
1        1001      sample1
2        1003      sample2
3        1005      sample3
```

I tried the `Select virCol = row_number() over (order by EmpID), EmpID, EmpName from EmpTable Where EmpName Like '%sam%'`

But I got this output

```
virCol   EmpID     EmpName
1        1001      sample1
3        1003      sample2
5        1005      sample3
```

What is the SQL to have virtual column for counting? Because I will further use that into something like this: 
`Select virCol, EmpID, EmpName from EmpTable Where EmpName Like '%sam%' AND virCol between 1 and 2`
to have this Output:

```
virCol   EmpID     EmpName
1        1001      sample1
2        1003      sample2
```

**EDIT**

My Actual Query and Output

```
        select * from(
select 
       Row,
       BookTitleID, 
       BookTitle,
       CallNumber,
       FullName,
       CopiesOnShelves

from
(  
    select 
           Book.BookTitleID,
           BookTitles.BookTitle,
           BookTitles.CallNumber,
           FullName = LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName,
           CopiesOnShelves = count(case Status when 'OnShelf' then 1 else null end),  
           Row = row_number() over (order by BookTitle)
    From
        Book
            left outer join 
        BookTitles
            on BookTitles.BookTitleID = Book.BookTitleID 
            left outer join
        Authors
            on Authors.AuthorID = BookTitles.AuthorID   

     Group By Book.BookTitleID, BookTitles.BookTitle, BookTitles.CallNumber, 
        LastName, FirstName, MiddleName
) sub
) sub2
Where BookTitle like '%some%'
Order By Row
```

[image]

All joined data wihout where clause

[image]

AuthorsTable

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Authors](
    [AuthorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Authors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AuthorID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

BookTable

```
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[book](
    [AccessionNumber] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BookTitleID] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Barcode]  AS ([AccessionNumber]+(100000)),
    [DateAcquired] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_book_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AccessionNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

BookTitles Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BookTitles](
    [BookTitleID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BookTitle] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CallNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AuthorID] [int] NULL,
    [YearOfPublication] [smallint] NULL,
    [Edition] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Publisher] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ISBN] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Subject1Number] [int] NULL,
    [Subject2Number] [int] NULL,
    [Copies] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BookTitles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BookTitleID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Authors Data

[image]

Book Data

[image]

Book Titles Data

[image]

Comment: The query you tried gives the output you expect. There's some other reason for skipping row numbers. ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6dac0/6) showing your query.)

Comment: Sorry the first examples is not tested I thought it is just the same as in my actual query. Please take a look in my Edit. Thank you.

Comment: Add CREATE TABLE statements and actual sample data to your question.

Comment: I use 3 tables. Its alright to post that?

Comment: It's ok to post the CREATE TABLE statements for 3 tables. Include just enough sample data to illustrate the problem. You should need just a few rows for each table.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6dac0/14)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE EmpTable
    ([EmpID] int, [EmpName] varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO EmpTable
    ([EmpID], [EmpName])
VALUES
    (1001, 'sample1'),
    (1002, 'test1'),
    (1003, 'sample2'),
    (1004, 'test2'),
    (1005, 'sample3')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
Select virCol = row_number() over (order by EmpID), 
       EmpID, EmpName 
from (Select EmpID, 
             EmpName 
      from EmpTable 
      Where EmpName Like '%sam%') EmpTable
ORDER BY 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6dac0/14/0)**:

```
| VIRCOL | EMPID | EMPNAME |
|--------|-------|---------|
|      1 |  1001 | sample1 |
|      2 |  1003 | sample2 |
|      3 |  1005 | sample3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your Where BookTitle like '%some%' inside the sub query, so query would be filtered before numbering:

```
select * from(
select 
       Row,
       BookTitleID, 
       BookTitle,
       CallNumber,
       FullName,
       CopiesOnShelves

from
(  
    select 
           Book.BookTitleID,
           BookTitles.BookTitle,
           BookTitles.CallNumber,
           FullName = LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName,
           CopiesOnShelves = count(case Status when 'OnShelf' then 1 else null end),  
           Row = row_number() over (order by BookTitle)
    From
        Book
            left outer join 
        BookTitles
            on BookTitles.BookTitleID = Book.BookTitleID 
            left outer join
        Authors
            on Authors.AuthorID = BookTitles.AuthorID   
     Where BookTitle like '%some%'

     Group By Book.BookTitleID, BookTitles.BookTitle, BookTitles.CallNumber, 
        LastName, FirstName, MiddleName
) sub
) sub2
Order By Row
```